# JavaScript RegExp to match "%.*", but not "\%.*"

Tags: javascript, regex, latex, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to improve upon the LaTeX brush used by Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter. The brush I found online correctly matches LaTeX comments, which start with `%`, but gets it wrong when it is escaped `\%`; i.e., it thinks the latter is also a comment.

The RegExp used in the brush is `%.*`. I figured that a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)%.*` would work, but JavaScript doesn't support this... Any other ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps `[^\\]%.*` would do? (This includes the character in front of `%` in the match though.

Comment: I can't praise this tool highly enough for figuring out RegExp http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: That's a great tool! Thanks, @MrMisterMan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you could use this `([^\\]|^)%.*` saying either its not \ or it is start of line

Comment: Thanks, both :) I tried this -- and also something similar, but less sophisticated -- but for some reason it breaks the highlighter. I did some investigating and found that, for some reason, the highlighter needs \ to be escaped several times: so the working RegExp is `([^\\\\\]|^)%.*`

Comment: (I feel torn as to who should get the tick!... Blem gets it for being first; but I'll keep an eye out for you, El Ronnoco, to balance your karma ;)

Comment: @Xophmeister You definitely made the right decision on the tick front. Blem was there first with exactly the same answer. I've no idea why you have to do the `\\\\\ ` business... are you building your regex directly in code or passing it to something else? (afraid I don't know about Latex/Highlighter). Anyway - at least it works. Absence of lookbehind is annoying in JS!

Comment: @ElRonnoco I was successfully able to change it to `\\\\`, which implies that the slashes need to be escaped themselves; so it must be being parsed elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
([^\\]|^)%.*
```

To match the start of the string or a non `\` character...?